# Facebook Oauth 2.0 and rate limiting

Tags: facebook, f#, social-networking

I am trying to extract Facebook ids from a list of emails using the url:

```
let url = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=" 
          + email.Replace("@","%40") 
          + "&type=user&access_token=" 
          + facebook.Token
```

After around 600 id extracts I get the error  "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.". Is the facebook API/Search rate limited? If so where is the doc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook limits you to 600 calls/600 sec - but it does reset after 10 minutes. I can't find the documentation at the moment, but I was told this at a Facebook developer garage

Comment: They really need to document it better, there are different rate limits for different tables, different token/ip combos, etc., but its just mentioned here and there.

Comment: @thefreeman I completely agree, I've found that things like Developer garages are essential if you ever want to rely on Facebook as a service

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I will have to look for some in my area.  On the off chance someone gets here from google, there is a bug report facebook has knowledge addressing the lack of documentation surrounding rate limits.  Subscribe if you want to bring attention to the issue: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/403200179756508